# I am not able to achieve this kind of image grid with bootstrap. Any suggestions?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to achieve this(http://www.blacktie.co/demo/basic/) full width responsive gallery with bootstrap but I have not managed to figure it out. I'd appreciate a snippet. And another thing is there would be alot of images in the future so is there any other easier way to add images instead of adding chunks of code?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: you can find tutorials online... also if you are looking for snippets check this site http://bootsnipp.com/

Comment: *I have not managed to figure it out.* - If you want help, you should ask a specific question about the problem you're having and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You're actually able to see for yourself how it's done.  On any given webpage, the browser gives you the ability to see the website's front-end source code.

On Chrome, this is: Settings > More Tools > Developer Tools

For the website in question, it appears the developer is, indeed, using Bootstrap.

He's also using the `::before` and `::after` selectors to achieve the intended look.

Here's a read-up on the `::before` selector:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need a specific height for creating a grid like that. So you need to get a specific height for it.

Try this its without using Bootstrap in pure CSS (*use full screen*):

```css
.img-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid {
  flex-basis: calc(20% - 2px);
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.grid .text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.8);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-grid">
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!